# Content Search Web Part news slider

Tags: search, content, web

I want to display news list as image slider on my SharePoint 2013 site. I have used content search web part, Its showing news list title but not showing images and also news slider height and width not getting increase. Kindly help me. In advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

search web part uses display template to render result items, you can create you own display template and adjust HTML and CSS, you can also add body of the news item.
[detail here](http://www.benprins.net/2014/05/21/sharepoint-2013-custom-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part/)

Comment: Can you give a sample code of display template i.e. Control and Item template. I am facing problem to create own display template. I don't know exactly where I have to edit control and Item template(in terms of height and width of image, rotation style). In advance Thanks.

Comment: you can use image slider comes with sharepoint http://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results

Comment: if you want to create your own http://sp2013.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/sharepoint-content-search-web-part.html

Comment: I have modified control and item template for height and width of news slider using .cbs-Slideshow,.cbs-largePictureContainer,.cbs-largePictureImageContainer classes but image height and width not getting increased. I have tried .cbs-largePictureImg class but also image height and width not getting increased. Image is displayed from center leaving margin on left and right. I want image to be display as whole container.Help me. Advance Thank you.

Comment: you can now get help from a web developer. please accept my answer if i have given you enough information.